# Setting a function parameter, which is of type pointer to a function to default value

Tags: c++, templates, default

Suppose we have the following function declaration

```
 template<typename Function_type , typename Iterator_type>
   Iterator_type sort(Iterator_type begin, Iterator_type end, Function_type f);
```

This function is supposed to mimic one of the many sort functions contained in the *algorithm* library, therefore having a third parameter which is optional. What value do i need to assign to *f* in this declaration to make avoiding the last parameter legal. My initial thought was to use a lambda function

```
 template<typename Function_type , typename Iterator_type>
  Iterator_type sort(Iterator_type begin, Iterator_type end, Function_type f=[](decltype(*begin)x, decltype(*begin)y){return x>y;});
```

This yielded a result in which the compiler informed me that f cannot be used as a function.

In my second attempt I declared another generic function

```
 template< typename Type>
  bool Comparison(Type x, Type y)
    {
    return y>x;
    }
 template<typename Function_type , typename Iterator_type>
  Iterator_type sort(Iterator_type begin, Iterator_type end, Function_type f=Comparison);
```

Still, I didn't succeed. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Don't* assign a default value. Just add an overload:

```
template <typename Iter>
Iter Max_el(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    using T = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*begin)>;
    return Max_el(begin, end, std::greater<T>{});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an instanciation of [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) as a default argument:

```
template<typename Iterator_type, typename Function_type = std::greater<void>>
Iterator_type sort(Iterator_type begin, Iterator_type end, Function_type f = Function_type())
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3994907c92729097)

Comment: I see, but is there a more generalized way, where we can use any arbitrary function?

Comment: @Shema Why do you think this is not general enough?

Comment: So what you are implying is that we should always use generic functions wrapped up in a class(which is how I picture these things)?

Comment: This doesn't compile for me under VS2015. It says that it can't deduce the type of Function_type.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ Your demo doesn't actually demo your function :)

Comment: @Shema No, I say that `std::greater` is a good default if you want to default to using `operator>` for the given type in your function. I think that `std::sort` uses `std::less` as a default too.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ Try calling it with two arguments.